# Docker Permission denied script sh

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm using jenkins docker image to run jenkins.
When i try to build docker image it is saying to Docker Permission Denied.
I'm running it on MAC OS! How can i add jenkin user to Docker Group?

Dockerfile:

```
    FROM python:3.7-alpine

CMD [ "python", "-c", "print('Hi there!')"]
```

Jenkinsfile:

```
   pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage("build") {
      steps {
        sh """
          docker build -t hello_there .
        """
      }
    }
    stage("run") {
      steps {
        sh """
          docker run --rm hello_there
        """
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. 
It is not clear which image you use, and which command produces the problem. 
Please provide a minimal working environment, e.g., post the commands you execute along with a minimal configuration.

Comment: @KartalTabak Please check now.

Answer (score 0):

Try run your jenkins container like this
It works in Ubuntu I think it should be ok in other OS too.

```
sudo docker run -d -v jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home     -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000     -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock 4oh4/jenkins-docker
```